# Полон чем и чего - в одном предложении. Можно (ль)?

Tags: управление

> И **город** снова **полон** беспечного **гомона** и **россыпями**
>   счастливого смеха.

Неужто **россыпей**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Можно использовать один падеж**

*И город снова полон беспечным **гомоном и россыпями** счастливого смеха.*

Я посмотрела ответы [https://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=полный+чего](https://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Мне показалась разумной **трактовка вариантов**, когда подчеркивается или сама наполненность (Р.п.), или наполненность чем (Т.п.).

В этом случае: *И город снова полон (= заполнен) беспечным гомоном и россыпями счастливого смеха.*

2) **Можно оставить всё как есть**

Формально Р.п. более привычен для слуха, когда существительное следует **сразу  за прилагательным**. Но чем дальше находится существительное от слова *полон*, тем более свободным кажется выбор падежа.

К тому же можно предположить, что **не все существительные сочетаются** с этим прилагательным в Р.п. (полон россыпей?), поэтому **два разных падежа смотрятся в принципе неплохо.**