# Можно ли считать устаревшей форму «полный/полон водой»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, управление

1. **Вот ответ Грамоты-ру.** Вопрос № 245837  Как правильно: **«стакан полон воды» или «стакан полон водой»?** Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: **полон (чего?) воды.**
2. **Вот статья** из современного словаря грамматической сочетаемости (Е.М. Лазуткина, 2013 год, словари РАН), ссылка на нее дана в ответе: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423986/Полон-бодрости-или-полон-бодростью](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423986/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E).

В этом словаре действительно говорится о том, что во всех значениях, в том числе в переносном значении  (с отвлеченными существительными), в настоящее время используется родительный падеж, а творительный  назван **устаревшим**.  Этот факт подтверждается и **примерами из Нацкорпуса**, так как в старых текстах творительный падеж использовался часто, да и сейчас его иногда, хотя и редко можно встретить.

3. Но  **не все пользователи согласны**  с тем, что Т.п. устарел, так как  видят семантическую разницу между количественным значением Р.п. и  «качественным» значением Т.п. (чем именно полный). Да и в словаре  Кузнецова  (на Грамоте.ру) для разных значений прилагательного «полный» допускаются оба падежа.
4. Мне же уже чисто **на слух** сочетания «реки, полные водой»  и «глаза, полные слезами или любовью» **кажутся странными.** Улицы полны народом, машинами?  Нет, так неправильно!
5. **Есть ли исключения?** Бывают, наверное.  Не стоит забывать о причастии «заполненный», которое управляет Т.п. и которым можно заменить прилагательное «полный».  Вот один из возможных примеров: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/451684/Полон-чем-и-чего-в-одном-предложении-Можно-ль](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/451684/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%8C)

И вопросы;

1. Какой падеж вы используете  в сочетаниях с прилагательным «полный/полон»?
2. Вы согласны с тем, что Т.п. вполне авторитетные источники считают устаревшим? (Это, кстати, соответствует действительности).
3. Почему Р.п. вытеснил (или вытесняет) Т.п.?

**Примечание:  интересный диалог из недавней темы**  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462171/Рассердиться-на-шутку-рассержен-шуткой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462171/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

– А можно сказать: "графин, полный водой". Или всё всё-таки нужно говорить только: "графин, полный воды"?

– Здесь не решают домашние задания. Если вы хотите, чтобы вам дали ответ, создайте отдельную тему под новый вопрос и изложите свои соображения. Как минимум, напишите сами, считаете ли вы, можно ли так сказать.

**Неужели это вопрос из домашнего задания?** Да, у нас тут всё строго. Но вот у меня точно не домашнее задание, а свои соображения я изложила.

Answer (score 1):

Ну что ж, вопрос никому неинтересен. Хотела его удалить, но всё-таки решила оставить – может быть, гостям форума будет любопытно почитать, вдруг такие найдутся.Поэтому отвечаю на вопрос сама.

Я полагаю, что   разница  в значении родительного и творительного падежа  оказалась для прилагательного «полный»  **несущественной,** поэтому и остался (**как более актуальный**) количественный Р.п., а не Т.п. с «качественным» значением.

Творительный же  падеж **ушел на периферию,** стал применяться в частных случаях, когда следует логически подчеркнуть  **именно содержимое** наполненного предмета. А это важно сделать **при противопоставлении**, как, например, для слова «красный»: «Не красна изба углАми, а красна пирогАми».

Для прилагательного «полный» такую ситуацию сложнее подобрать,  но вот,  к примеру,  могу предложить такое начало:  «Не водОй полны бокалы, а  винОм…».  Продолжать не буду, оставлю  желающим в качестве творческого задания.

Творческое задание никто не выполнил.  Где вы, поэты и любители изящной словесности? Нет их здесь, одни лингвисты остались. Тогда сама закончу стих: *Не водОй полны бокалы, а винОм. Не теплОм любовь согреет, а огнЁм.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ  (примеры из   Нацкорпуса)**

Сапог не снимали ― сапоги давно уже были полны **воды**. [Василь Быков. (2001)]

Круглые цилиндры из грубого стекла помещены в сосуд, наполовину полный **воды**. [Ю. М. Нагибин. (1956)]

Журналист толкает дверь и попадает в гримерку, посреди которой стоит, прямо на досках, ванная. Она полна **воды** [В. В. Лорченков. Бездна (2012)]

Я бегу к дому. Канавы полны **водой**. Плывут доски и бревна.  [М. М. Зощенко. (1943)]

Англия, как губка, полна **водой подземной**, помимо рек и озер. [Алексей Кузнецов. (2002)]

Answer (score 1):

Процитирую по случаю Н.Ю. Шведову ("Русская грамматика", 1980 г.). В параграфе, посвящённом вариативности управления, сказано:

> ...В слове могут взаимодействовать семантические элементы разных собственно лексико-семантических классов. Так, вариативность связи **полный воды** и **полный водой** поддерживается наличием связей *налить воды* (насыпать песку, набросать камней...) и *наполнить водой* (заполнить камнями, набить вещами...);

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Всё-таки статистика для воды/водой  не в пользу Т.п. Из Нацкорпуса: полный воды (21), полны воды (22), полна воды (7);  полный водой (0), полны водой (10, старые тексты), полна водой (3).

Comment: @Sharon, я не могу понять, как Вы ищете в Нацкорпусе и почему так мало находите. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на [результаты моего поиска](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?text=lexgramm&level1=0&level2=0&api=1.0&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&env=alpha&nodia=1&parent2=0&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&gramm2=ins&min2=1&lang=ru&lex1=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&lex2=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&max2=1&endyear=2019&mode=main&parent1=0&p=0) (это, наверное, не всё — зачастую нужно создать несколько различных запросов, чтобы увидеть побольше вариантов).

Comment: Но я согласен, конечно, что статистика не в пользу Т.п. Но ведь это недостаточное основание для запрета менее распространённого варианта? Иначе мы быстро скатимся в какой-то машинный язык, не имеющий никаких перспектив.

Comment: Ну да,  я не так ищу, а что такое ins, как  его установить при поиске.

Comment: @Sharon, попробую объяснить словами. Блок "точный поиск форм" оставил пустым; в блоке "Лексико-грамматический поиск" пишу слово "полный" и на "Расстоянии от 1 до 1" второе слово "вода". В соседней колонке проставляем "грамматические признаки" — только для слова "вода" выбираем Т.п. в колонке "Падеж" (и подтверждаем кнопкой "Ок" внизу). Скажите, получилось или нет. Если на словах непонятно, я попробую продублировать на скриншоте.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!